# What does the *[ ... ] syntax mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I was wondering if someone could direct me to some documentation on what the `*[ ... ]` does in this example of converting columns to lowercase in a pyspark dataframe

```
df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[c.lower() for c in df.columns]` construct will create an array with the columns converted to lowercase, and the `*` in front of the array means that the array elements will be sent as individual arguments to `df.toDF()`.
E.g. if the array is `a=[1,2,"b"]` then `df.toDF(*a)` is equivalent to `df.toDF(1,2,"b")`.